# Giving a directive a custom attribute.

Tags: angularjs

### Directive

```
function CreateTable() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            pageName: '=',
        },
        templateUrl: 'Hexdra/partials' + pageName + '-table.html',
    };
    return directive;
};
```

### The Template Html

```
  <table ng- controller="TableController as TblCtrl">
    <tr ng-repeat-start="data in TblCtrl.table" ng-if="$first">
     <th>{{::data.col1}}</th>
     <th>{{::data.col2}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end>
    <td>{{data.col1}}</td>
    <td><input disabled type="checkbox" ng-checked="data.col2" ng- model="checkbox"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

### The Html

```
<site-table pageName="goals" class="span6"></site-table>
```

When beginning to make tables for my website, I found myself making a new directive for every table around the site, even though thats only 4 seperate directives, I know that there has to be a way to make a general-directive that I can then add, something, to make it so that the directive will load both a unique templateUrl and also a unique JSON file that is used to populate the table with data that is unique to each individual table.

I went [looking](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-) and found that you can [create your own attributes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#) in the html, as shown in section The Html above. In this case i added a new attribute, `pageName`. In the example it is `"goals"`. Im trying to get my `<site-table>` directive to assign that attribute to the scope of the Directive, where it will then complete and evaluate `templateUrl` as `Hexdra/partials/goals-table.html`

Currently though I am left with a blank page and a error in the console that `pageName is undefined`.

I feel like I am missing something very important that happens between when a directive is called and when it is finished. Perhaps this is a good time to get into ng-Route?

Thank you for looking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this in two ways:

templateUrl and ng-include in template.

Application:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});


app.directive("commondir1", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: true,
    templateUrl: function (element, attr) {
      return 'Hexdra/partials' + attr.pageName + '-table.html';
    },
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {

    }
  };
});

app.directive('commondir2', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      pageName : '@'
    },
    template: '<ng-include src="pageName"></ng-include>'
  };
});
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/IXetkYMHCxsgAsyqA3SM

Comment: I used the commondir1 as I like how its implemented better and it is what I was looking for, but I have a few questions. Why does your implementation of the templateUrl work while mine does not? What is the empty link: functions purpose? The funtion you used for templateUrl, does it pull all elements and attributes in the scope?

Comment: if you use `'Hexdra/partials' + pageName + '-table.html'` in your `templateUrl `, the pageName will not be available because the scope is not evaluated yet.